# Button lib/API for digg, twitter, facebook etc?

Tags: facebook, twitter, web

Multiple sites have buttons where you can tweet, digg, etc. On [this page](http://vladioglas.deviantart.com/art/Dark-mansion-1-160362230) you'll see you can buttons for 6 sites (search twitter and you'll see them).

Is there a lib or api i can use to generate these buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bookmarkit.org

http://addthis.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a quick look at the urls the buttons link to.

This is the one for twitter:

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=Check+out+http%3A%2F%2Ffav.me%2Fd2nh4ae+on+%23deviantart
```

If we undo the url-encoding this is what we'll get:

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=Check out http://fav.me/d2nh4ae on #deviantart
```

You don't need a library to generate those, it's just very simple string manipulations. All you need to know is the format for the specific sharing site (which you can snatch from wherever) and the url for the page you want to share.

Comment: hmm. it looks simple enough. The last two are complex and i am hoping a lib can have more sites. Also i need to grab images. I guess i could do this without. +1